# magento cms pages index page not open in admin panel

Tags: magento, magento-1.4, magento-1.5

I'm using Magento 1.4.1.1 which works great other than the cms menu in the admin panel when i try to open the cms->pages in admin navigarion it shows the error '404 error:Page not found'.
All other pages work great and even other items in CMS menu, only Pages gives 404.
What should I do?
Can any one help me how to trace the error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you enable log reports in system->configuration->advanced->developer ?

Comment: thanks for response.Yes i enabled the log system , what should i do next..

Comment: go to cms->pages, get the 404 error, open the log file and see what is your error related to.

Comment: I check the log file the error is.
Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/home/content/86/7738286/html/errors/404.php' (include_path='/home/content/86/7738286/html/app/code/local:/home/content/86/7738286/html/app/code/community:/home/content/86/7738286/html/app/code/core:/home/content/86/7738286/html/lib:.:/usr/local/php5/lib/php') in /home/content/86/7738286/html/app/Mage.php on line 602

Comment: this is really strange. it seem it can't read your 404.php file. are you sure your folder permissions are ok? did you try to clear cache and do some check on the content of your folders?

Comment: sorry for delay replying, yes i checked my folders and i found that there is no folder permissions for errors folder now i given the 777 permissions for that folder. but i can't get the pages index instead of that i get the magento 404 error please tell me how to rectify that error.

Comment: this is not a normal behavior: did you deleted some file? did you change some settings? is it a fresh magento install? did you check .htaccess for some problem? sorry, but the problem could be anywhere..

Comment: finally i got the solution. I modified the core_store table in magento database why because there had a conflict occured in the store id. i maintain  2 stores in previous, i deleted one of the store later for some reasons, now i changed the store id. then its working fine. Thanks for **notme** and his patience with me.

Comment: you are welcome. happy to know you solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the core_store table in magento database why because there had a conflict occured in the store id. i maintain 2 stores in previous, i deleted one of the store later for some reasons, now i changed the store id. then its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually due to residual entries in the database from previous stores (and store IDs).

Run this SQL command to clear these up:

```
DELETE FROM cms_page_store WHERE store_id NOT IN (SELECT store_id FROM core_store)
```